# Python, comparing sub-list items with other in same list

Tags: python, list, sublist

i have a list as follows:

```
 lis=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,9],[6,8]]
```

In my program i have to build a function takes the list as input and return bool value after applying the rule on the list:

If both values for element is greater than both values for all elements return true (e.g. [1,2] and [3,4]), If not for both value, we need to check if the first element is less than first element of previous item and the second value is less than the second value of its previous. (e.g. [5,9] and [6,8]) this is true because 6 >5 and 8<9.
my function looks like:

```
def ORDER_LINK(L):
    if len(L)==2:
        return L[0][0] < L[1][0] and L[0][1] < L[1][1]
    H=L[0]
    T=L[1:]
    if H > T:
        return False
    else:
        return ORDER_LINK(T)
```

but it gives me some errors

Comment: That rule is a bit confusing. And you didn't tell us what the result is of applying that rule to `lis`, `a`, `b`, and `c`,

Comment: The statement `if H > T` tries to compare a list of int with a list of lists, which generates one error. In a list. `if` will compare elements but now you try to compare an `int` from H with a `list` from T.